# Spectral theorem and strong convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Question:Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and $T$ be a self-adjoint operator. If $||T||\leq 1$ and $(Tx,x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in H$, then $T^n$ strongly convergent.

My idea : By spectral theorem and $||T||\leq 1$, $Tx=\int _{-1}^{1} \lambda dE_\lambda x$. I guess $T^n$ strongly convergent to $0$. But I can't compute $T^nx$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2735766/prove-strong-convergence-in-hilbert-space/2847719#2847719

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $T^n$ is a decreasing net of positive elements, by Vigier's theorem(Theorem 4.1.1, *C*-algebras and operator theory* by Murphy), $T^n$ is strongly convergent.

Answer (score 2):

The spectrum of $T$ is contained on $[0,1]$ because $(Tx,x)\ge 0$ and $\|T\| \le 1$. So,
$$
        T^n x = \int_{0}^{1}\lambda^n dE(\lambda)x \rightarrow E\{1\}x,
$$

which is the projection onto the eigenspace of $T$ with eigenvalue $1$. This strong convergence is obvious from

$$
    \|T^n x - E\{1\}x\|^2 \\
= \left\|\int_{0}^{1}(\lambda^n-\chi_{\{1\}}(\lambda))dE(\lambda)x\right\|^2 \\
= \int_{0}^{1}|\lambda^n-\chi_{\{1\}}(\lambda)|^2 d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2.
$$

Comment: I think it is necessary to explain why $\int_{\sigma (T)}\lambda^ndE(\lambda)x\to E{\{1\}}x$.

Comment: @C.Ding : Because $\lambda^n$ converges to $\chi_{\{1\}}(\lambda)$ on $[0,1]$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @C.Ding : Is there something not obvious about that?

Comment: In fact, I'm asking why does $\lambda\to \chi_{\{1\}}$ imply $\int_{\sigma(T)}\lambda^ndE(\lambda)x\to E(\{1\})x$.

Comment: @C.Ding : $\lambda^n \rightarrow \chi_{\{1\}}$ on $[0,1]$ gives the strong convergence of $\int_{\sigma(T)}\lambda^{n}dE(\lambda)\rightarrow \int \chi_{\{1\}}(\lambda)dE(\lambda) = E\{1\}$ because $\sigma(T)\subseteq [0,1]$.

Comment: I know the pointwise convergence of uniform bounded net of bounded Borel measurable functions implies the weak convergence of the functional calculus, and weak convergence is equal to strong convergence when the uniform bounded net of  operators is monotonous. Are you using this proposition? or is there any proposition can directly support your assetion?

Comment: $\|f(T)x-g(T)x\|^2 = \int_{\sigma{T}}|f(t)-g(t)|^2 d\|E(t)x\|^2$. So the functional calculus is continuous in the strong topology if the functions converge pointwise and in a dominated way.